# Community Builder: Add more than 20 navigation menu items in Salesforce community builder Navigation Menu

Tags: community

I am new to Salesforce Community Builder. I want to add more than 20  top-level Navigation Menu items in the Navigation Menu but I cannot do so as this is a limitation enforced by Salesforce. Is there any workaround to achieve this?

[image]